# What is another word for a reason that is "not the real reason"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The real reason is what you get if you go a couple of levels deep. Why do you do go to work? Because I have a job. But why? Because I need to make money. But why? Because we live in a capitalist society where goods and services are exchanged by money and I can get money by helping somebody else achieve their goal.

So how can I describe the first two reasons: superficial, smoke-screen, non-real?

Comment: _Surface-level_ sounds less pejorative than _superficial_ (though that works in the right environment). The 'reasons' given are neither 'non-real' (they are approaches to the truth and true in themselves) nor necessarily 'smoke-screen' (designed to guard the truth).

Comment: [*A **proximate cause** is an event which is closest to, or immediately responsible for causing, some observed result. This exists in contrast to a higher-level **ultimate cause** (or **distal cause**) which is usually thought of as **the "real" reason** something occurred.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_and_ultimate_causation)

Comment: @FumbleFingers interesting! But then we get into the debate of is a cause the same as a reason? Never mind, I guess a reason is the same as a cause.

Comment: @nachocab: Hmm. By any reasonable standards, I'd have thought *cause* and *reason* are synonymous in the context of philosophical discussions concerning proximate and distal causes. At some point you could split off the concept of *reason = justification = excuse*, but we're getting into very murky waters there regarding the nature of "free will" (researchers having discovered relatively recently that human beings apparently *always* commit to their choice before they have any conscious awareness of how they will subsequently justify it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah, you're right. It makes more sense the more I think about it.

Comment: Buy this car to drive to work
Drive to work to pay for this car

Comment: But isn't your last statement just a smoke screen?  *Why* do you need goods and services?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximate_and_ultimate_causation)

> *A **proximate cause** is an event which is closest to, or immediately responsible for causing, some observed result. This exists in contrast to a higher-level ultimate cause (or **distal cause**) which is usually thought of as **the "real" reason** something occurred.*

Comment: 'Cause' and 'reason' are not always identical. There is more of an inevitability, a forcing, associated with _cause_.

Comment: @Edwin: Not *always* identical, no (well, true synonyms are rare, if they exist at all). But per earlier comment, I think they are in this specific context. Why? Are you unhappy with Wikipedia obviously using *[real] **reason*** as a synonym above? It seems perfectly natural to me.

Comment: I may have a [very good] reason to go to the bank. But I'm not forced / caused to go to the bank. [West's Encyclopedia of American Law, edition 2](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/proximate+cause) has '**Proximate Cause** 
An act from which an injury results as a natural, direct, uninterrupted consequence and without which the injury would not have occurred.' So a cause entails an event. With OP's example, there is a good reason to work, but no entailment. // I'd say Wikipedia uses 'reason' in the overlap sense, but that this sense doesn't apply to OP's example.

Comment: I appreciate the debate, but I think **surface-level** is more common than **proximate**.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason offered is a plausible fake, with bad intent, then you're talking about a **pretext**.

> **pretext**: a purpose or motive alleged or an appearance assumed in order to cloak the real intention or state of affairs
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretext

If, as the example in your post implies, the reason given is just simpler or easier to understand, then I think you probably can't outdo *superficial reason* as describing exactly what you're talking about.

There is also *putative reason*, but a putative reason is a *pretext.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer "immediate reason" as a an answer. As in, "The immediate reason I go to work is because I have a job, but the real underlying reason is because we live in a capitalist society".

Answer (score 0):

Also consider a **hollow reason**. It's idiomatic and doesn't show up in many idiom dictionaries, but there are plenty of decent examples of it.

[image]

[image]

> The research team had a stranger approach someone waiting in line to use a photocopier and asked if they could go before that person with no reason – just simply “ I have five copies to make, can I use the photocopier?’  – 60% of people allowed the person to go ahead.  When the stranger made the same request with a reason… ‘because I am in a rush” – compliance jumped to 94%, which may not be surprising to you.  Here’s where it got very interesting!  The stranger then made the same request but this time used a completely meaningless reason – “may I use the photocopier because I have to make copies”.  Despite this hollow reason (everyone was there to make copies after all), the compliance rate was almost the same(93%) ie nearly everyone said ‘yes’.

http://www.vikkikelly.com/dorothy-and-her-friends-had-it-right/

I suggest that this idiom is better suited to pointing out logically incongruent "reasons" than suggesting duplicity or cunning.

Answer (score 0):

These reasons which are linked to each other in a chain and finally to the actual reason may be called the *(causal) **links***.

ODO:

> **[link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/link)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A relationship between two things or situations, especially where one affects the other:
>   ‘a commission to investigate a link
>   between pollution and forest decline’
>
> ‘In these circumstances, and without more, it seems to me that the
>   necessary causal link is sufficiently established.’
>
> **[causal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/causal)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Relating to or acting as a cause:
>   ‘the causal factors associated with illness’

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.

Answer (score 0):

How about **root reason**, which is akin to **root cause**?

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [**root
>   cause**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/root_cause): the
>   basic cause of something
>
> [**root**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/root): the
>   basic cause, source, or origin of something

The **root reason** is more fundamental that *proximate reason* or d*istal reason* or *causal reason*. It is the answer to the last *why* in the chain of *whys*. And it differs from **root cause**, as *reason* and *cause* mean different things.