# Concise Word/Concept for: "Deceiving with a GOOD reason, to hide their REAL reason"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a concept/technical word in law, politics, psychology, literature (e.g. George Orwell), signalling theory etc for
the following deceptive technique, process or phenomena:

The act of avowing that something is motivated by:

> A good reason

But it is actually for a:

> Hidden, less noble, reason

The deception functions this way: the avowed reason acts as a cover-story for the true-but-concealed reason.

I’ll give a political-revolutionary example:

> Avowed: We are doing this for the people

> Real:   We are doing this to establish a dictatorship

And a political commentator could say:

The revolutionaries are _________ {NAME OF DECEPTIVE
TECHNIQUE, PROCESS OR PHENOMENA}

The revolutionaries are using _________ {NAME OF DECEPTIVE TECHNIQUE, PROCESS OR PHENOMENA}

Here are a bunch of examples of other psychological methods that would fit the empty slots:

---

- The revolutionaries are Love bombing
- The revolutionaries are Nudging
- The revolutionaries are Low-balling
- The revolutionaries are Fearmongering
- The revolutionaries are Baiting-and-switching
- The revolutionaries are Gaslighting
- The revolutionaries are Virtue-signalling

---

- The revolutionaries are using Doublethink
- The revolutionaries are using Grey Propoganda
- The revolutionaries are using Bribery
- The revolutionaries are using Ingratiation
- The revolutionaries are using Superficial sympathy
- The revolutionaries are using Character assassination
- The revolutionaries are using Emotional blackmail
- The revolutionaries are using Intimidation
- The revolutionaries are using Nit-picking criticism

---

I'm trying to avoid nouns that require an article prefixed, e.g.

- The revolutionaries are using a gambit
- The revolutionaries are using a ruse
- The revolutionaries are using a pretext
- The revolutionaries are using a trojan horse
- The revolutionaries are using a trick

Ideally, I am looking for:

- a verb    ,or
- a noun (that doesn't require an article)

The word (if there is one) might resemble the form of some of these "Ericism":
https://theportal.wiki/wiki/Ericisms

or

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Deception

My question is not this:
[What is another word for a reason that is "not the real reason"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354817/what-is-another-word-for-a-reason-that-is-not-the-real-reason)

I think a **concise** word/concept to express this specific kind of two-sided deception would be very useful!

Thanks for reading

Comment: An example of a term for this deception could be: "Carlylian Deception" after a quote attributed to Thomas Carlyle:  "A person usually has two reasons for doing something: a good reason and the real reason. "

Comment: Another potential neologism: "Motivational Façadism"

Comment: They're ***[dissembling](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dissemble), dissimulating, propagandising, sanitising, whitewashing, smokescreening,...***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you rejected *pretext*. I can't think of anything that better maps to your description.

> **pretext**
>  <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A reason given in justification of a course of action that is not the
> real reason.
>  <sub>Source: [Lexico —
> *pretext*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pretext)</sub>

Here are some examples given:

> <sub>‘the rebels had the perfect pretext for making their move’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘The buzz is that the political agenda of the Minister's visit
> was merely a pretext.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘If not, we are again using a pretext to cover intervention that is really motivated by another purpose altogether.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘Of course, there are always good pretexts to postpone political reform.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘He has often sought to justify repression on the pretexts of threatened coups against his government.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘Any sign of opposition, real or imagined, was the pretext for a massive retaliation.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘We're the ones who unquestioningly march behind bullies into other countries on fictitious pretexts.’</sub>
>
> <sub>‘But it has become increasingly clear to them that the pretexts for the war were false.’</sub>
> .

Have a look at *pretext*'s synonym [*smoke screen*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/smoke_screen) (and its synonyms) for more ideas.

Comment: Hi Tinfoil Hat, thanks for your response, I have edited my question so as to be more clear, I think I didn't articulate it perfectly! Ideally I'm looking for a verb or a noun (without an article) - for that reason I discarded "a pretext".  If "To Smoke-screen" or "Smoke-screening" is a verb and can be used in the context of "concealing ones true reasons with a different reason" then that might work

Comment: Note that *pretext* does not need an article. *Smokescreen* is listed as a verb in the *OED*. Here's an example usage: *Earlier that day, John Foster Dulles had foxily smokescreened the operation by issuing a statement about summit talks with Russia.* And you can use it as a gerund (functioning like a noun): *The revolutionaries use smokescreening.*

Comment: Hi Tinfoil Hat, I think you are correct, that works well:

 "The revolutionaries are Smokescreening (us about their motives)"
"The revolutionaries are using Smokescreen Motives"

It has a military connotation and means “using one thing to obscure another”. That works well, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP rejected my original answer (below) because it requires an article, I'll try a verb:

> The revolutionaries are **masquerading**

**masquerade** (v.)

> To have or assume the appearance of something else. OED

> To disguise oneself
>
> To assume the appearance of something one is not [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/masquerade)

---

> And no wonder, for Satan himself **masquerades** as an
> angel of light. 2 Corinthians 11:14

> They are trying to convince the free world that the communists no
> longer are an armed revolutionary movement. Now they **masquerade** as
> a political, ideological movement. The people like it, and they bring
> as proof of it the election of Allende in Chile. [U.S. Congress; *The
> Theory and Practice of Communism in 1972, Southeast Asia, Part 1*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Theory_and_Practice_of_Communism_in/itCBydhZDeMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22They%20%20masquerade%22&pg=PA7968&printsec=frontcover)
> p.7968

> Suck-ups are *yes* people and as such, oppose clarity. When generous,
> they are telling you 50 percent of the truth and withholding the other
> 40 percent to serve their own purpose and to use strategically when it
> will best enhance their position.
>
> Suck-ups and people pleases are everywhere in every business. They
> **masquerade** as leaders, often found on the ladder to top positions or as a staff member... [Brad Deutser; *Leading Clarity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Leading_Clarity/3sFQDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22They%20%20masquerade%22&pg=PT143&printsec=frontcover)

> *The Battle of Algiers* thus underlines the racial and sexual taboos of desire within colonial segregation. As Algerians, the women are the
> objects of the military as well as the sexual gaze; they are publicly
> desirable for the soldiers, however, only when they **masquerade** as
> French. [W. Dissanayake and A. Guneratne; *Rethinking Third
> Cinema*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rethinking_Third_Cinema/aEaFAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22They%20%20masquerade%22&pg=PA58&printsec=frontcover)

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

**Trojan horse (issue)**

> Thus, the comments from a spokesperson for the DFAF that 'Medical
> marijuana is a **Trojan horse issue**, backed by a larger marijuana
> legalization effort' resonated with opponents of liberalization not
> only within the USA, but also no doubt the offices of the INCB in
> Vienna. [D. R. Bewley-Taylor; *International Drug Control*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/International_Drug_Control/1Oxm66EtvLcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22trojan%20horse%20issue%22%20medical%20marijuana&pg=PA180&printsec=frontcover)

> This November, Voters will decide on critical constitutional
> questions, which generally receive inadequate public discussion and
> debate.
>
> Amendment 1, known as the Water and Land Conservation amendemnt, is an innocuous-sounding proposal as very few people in
> the state of Florida, including myself, would oppose conserving water
> and land. However, careful examination finds that the amendment
> duplicates numerous existing environmental programs and creates
> dangerous constitutional funding mandates. ["Chris Muro: **A Trojan
> Horse issue**"](https://www.floridatoday.com/story/opinion/contributors/2014/08/05/chris-muro-trojan-horse-issue/13590873/)

> ...the mass marketing and high pressure promotion of infant formula to
> poverty populations in developing countries in not an acceptable
> technology transfer, from either health or economic perspectives.
> Those who engage in these practices are either closing their eyes to
> the consequences of their actions, or deliberately exporting a **Trojan
> horse**.
>
> Unfortunately, the infant formula issue is not the sole example of
> contemporary **Trojan horses** ... [J. R. Gay and B. J. Sax Jacobs; *The
> Technology Explosion in Medical Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YgO5BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=what%20is%20a%20%22trojan%20horse%20issue%22&source=bl&ots=1lCW6gIZhU&sig=ACfU3U2M58kGrCmMgPFqE1KtAmBam_NcXA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVgN6QkYrzAhX2TjABHQJ-DSYQ6AF6BAgiEAM#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20a%20%22trojan%20horse%20issue%22&f=false).

Comment: Hi DijnTonic, thanks for your reply, I have edited my above question to be more clear, Trojan Horse is actually near perfect conceptually, but ideally I'm looking for a verb or a noun (without an article) so "a Trojan Horse" doesn't fit. But perhaps the neologism "Trojan-horsing" works

Comment: @user13764383 I've changed my answer based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The verb counterpart of "pretext", that is "*to pretend*", should be fine.

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pretend)) to behave as if something is true when you know that it is not, especially in order to deceive people or as a game

- The revolutionaries are pretending